# Getting an error whenever I declare my function inside the Jswrapper at my React class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I'm getting an error whenever I declare my getDataFromApi function inside my class AppWrapper
[imageShowingError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEwG8.png)

The problem is that I thought just by putting them inside curly braces, the problem would be resolved, but I was wrong, can someone help me?

Comment: From the [Question Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or other things that require a graphical representation.